# upgrade an old android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

3 years ago I wrote an Android Java project in Android Studio. But due to some problems I had to stop its development and now after 3 years I want to revive it again.
I installed the latest version of Android Studio and its SDKs. But I can't update that project properly. I was also getting help from Android Studio and spent several hours searching the internet and stack overflow and I didn't get any results in every way I tried.
In fact, I can't sync gradle and even run the project.
Every time I got a new error
Errors like:

Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.

This is the result of my last efforts

Gradle JVM version incompatible.
This project is configured to use an older Gradle JVM that supports up to version 8, but the current AGP requires a Gradle JVM that supports version 17.

Occurs by updating classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0" to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1'

And a few other things that I will share if necessary to discuss in more detail
At the moment, I don't want to spread the discussion, my main question is how to update an old project in a standard and principled way.

It seems that there are some files that neither Android Studio updates nor I find them myself.
The only way I can think of is to create a new project and copy the code and files into it.
I am really tired and helpless

It seems that there are some files that neither Android Studio updates nor I find them myself.

Comment: I would first try to make the old project sync in Android Studio. Once that works AS provides a lot of upgrade helpers, that can even do things automatically. Don't try to perform upgrades manually, just use the old project and make the minimal required modifications to make it sync.

Comment: Just start a new project and copy the old java and xml files to it. Ready in ten minutes. Copy the files. You say copy code and files but copy files is all you have to do. Ten minutes.